# Applying Colnames() function on several objects in one code

Tags: r, list, dataframe, multiple-columns, quantmod

I have downloaded A LOT of equity data using the getSymbols function from Quantmod. I am now trying to change the column names for all of these to the following by using the code below:

```
StockColumnNames <- c("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted Close")
colnames() <- StockColumnNames
```

Now this works fine on just one stock, however, I have the data of about 800. I was wondering if there's anyway that I could do this in a small piece of code?

If I put the following in the code it gives me this error:

```
C20_stock_List <- c("NZYM-B.CO","DANSKE.CO","DSV.CO","CARL-B.CO","MAERSK-A.CO","WDH.CO","LUN.CO","TDC.CO","GN.CO","MAERSK-B.CO","NOVO-B.CO","COLO-B.CO","JYSK.CO","ISS.CO","VWS.CO","CHR.CO","GEN.CO","PNDORA.CO","NETS.CO")
getSymbols(C20_stock_List, from = '2017-01-01')
colnames(C20_stock_List) <- StockColumnNames

> colnames(C20_stock_List) <- StockColumnNames
```

> Error in `colnames<-`(``` *tmp*``, value = c("Open", "High", "Low",
>   "Close", ```  :    attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than
>   two dimensions

Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two approaches:

```
library(quantmod)
C20_stock_List <- c("NZYM-B.CO","DANSKE.CO","DSV.CO")
getSymbols(C20_stock_List, from = '2017-01-01')

StockColumnNames <- c("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted Close")
lapply(C20_stock_List, function(x, StockColumnNames_) {
  z <- get(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  colnames(z) <- StockColumnNames_
  assign(x, value = z, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  return()
}, StockColumnNames_ = StockColumnNames)
```

When getting multiple symbols, instead of having all the symbols appear in the `.GlobalEnv`, assign them into an environment.  This approach might be easier for most tasks related to looping across the data in each symbol:

```
e <- new.env()
getSymbols(C20_stock_List, from = '2017-01-01', auto.assign = TRUE, env = e)

for (sym in C20_stock_List) {
  colnames(e[[sym]]) <- StockColumnNames
}

head(e$DANSKE.CO)
```

Comment: thanks a bunch @FXQuantTrader. Think I'll go with the second option of assigning all these symbols into a new environment. Is is possible to do this for more than one set of data in the code above? example:                                                           C20_stock_List <- c("DANSKE.CO","NOVO-B.CO)                                                   DAX_stock_List <- c("SAP.DE","EOAN.DE")                                                        I know that these four simply could be made into one vector, but I have over 800 symbols in 5 different vectors. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Seem to have solved it, simply called:                                                                        allstocks<-c(a,,b,c,d,e,f,g)                                                                                      for (sym in allstocks) {
  colnames(e[[sym]]) <- StockColumnNames
}                                                                                                                           This worked perfectly, thanks a bunch again. Much appreciated